# Any way to process only part of a movie using GPUImage framework

Tags: ios, gpuimage

For example, the movie has 100 seconds. I'd like to seek to the 5th second of the movie, start processing then end processing at the 10th second of the movie.

Any way to do it using GPUImage framework? Any directions for modifying the framework to do it if it's not supported now?